# editing CSS for individual area

Tags: css

```
<form name="Form">
    Value1: <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"> <br />
    Value2: <input type="text" name="height" size="10"> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()"> <br />
    Answer: <input type="text" name="Finalvalue" size="10"> <br />
    This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"> <br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

I am looking to change the colour and position of the buttons along with the position of the text but regardless of what I try i cannot move them. I have tried using:

```
.form #button {
position:xx;
left: xx;
color:xx;}
```

and also tried adding that directly into the code

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()" position="xx" left="xx" color="xx"><br />
```

If i edit css for

```
.button {}
```

this ammends all code which uses button and I only want to edit this particular area

Any help would be appreciated

Update...

I changed CSS to:

```
form, [type=button] {
position: relative;
left: 100px;
background-color:#d52027 !important;
```

This seems to work for IE Edge but does not seem to do anything when viewing on Chrome.
Is there any reason for this?

Comment: `form[type="button"]` is what you're looking for. `.button` selects anything with `class="button"`, `#button` selects anything with `id="button"`, `form button` would select any `<button>` elements inside of a `<form>` element, which you have 0 of.  I suggest you check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for full explanations

Comment: it is `form [type="button"]` and not `form[type="button"]` for matching elements inside the form element

Comment: D'oh you're right.  I can't edit it anymore, but my above explanation should be `form input[type="button"]` to select the button type input only (note the space as @cornel.raiu mentioned).  Though I still think targeting with a class is cleaner (if they have multiple forms on their page, multiple button inputs, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```css
form [type=button], {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="Form">
    Value1: <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"> <br />
    Value2: <input type="text" name="height" size="10"> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()"> <br />
    Answer: <input type="text" name="Finalvalue" size="10"> <br />
    This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"> <br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

```
form [type=button] {
position: absolute;
left: 00px;
color: xx;    }
```

this should work
If you want both buttons then make the first line like this: 
`form input[type=button], form input[type="reset"] {`

Comment: Thanks a lot... Used this and it seems to work. but as I mentioned above... It only seems to work on IE. on Chrome it looks as it did before. have you any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding classes to the elements you want to adjust the styles of, so then your CSS targets the elements with that class directly.  My example below added `class="adjustPosition"` to the two inputs I think you're looking to adjust:

```
<form name="form">
    Value1: <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"> <br />
    Value2: <input type="text" name="height" size="10"> <br />
    <input type="button" class="adjustPosition" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()"> <br />
    Answer: <input type="text" name="Finalvalue" size="10"> <br />
    This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"> <br />
    <input type="reset" class="adjustPosition" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

So then your CSS just needs to be:

```
.adjustPosition {
    position: xx;
    left: xx;
    color: xx;
}
```

With your current HTML though (if you don't want to adjust that at all), you can change your CSS selector to the following in order to adjust the button/reset input types:

```
form input[type="button"], form input[type="reset"] {
    position: xx;
    left: xx;
    color: xx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is used to select for classes and `#` for ids.

So `.button` selects anything with `class="button"` and `#button` selects anything with `id="button"`.

To select all button inside a form you can use `form[type="button"]` and `form button` if there are `button` tag inside form.